# LINQ - How to get Single() review

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Here's my repeater to get the first book review:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("Reviews") %>' ItemType="ELibraryModel.Review">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="new_prod_box">
           <div class="new_prod_bg">
               <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" CssClass="thumb" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# String.Format("../Images/books/{0}.jpg", Item.Id.ToString()) %>' Text='<%# Item.Title %>' NavigateUrl='<%# "../books/bookdetails.aspx?reviewId=" + Item.Id.ToString() %>'></asp:HyperLink>
               <a><asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Item.Title %>' /></a>
           </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

On code behind I'm using something like this to get the first review and it works:

```
using (ELibraryEntities entities = new ELibraryEntities())
{
    var firstBook = (from books in entities.Books.Include("Reviews")
                     orderby books.Category
                     select new { books.Reviews }).Take(1);
    Repeater2.DataSource = firstBook;
    Repeater2.DataBind();
}
```

How can I get the review I want based on the review Id.

I'm trying something like this:

```
using (ELibraryEntities entities = new ELibraryEntities())
{
    var review = (from books in entities.Books.Include("Reviews")
                  where books.Id == 13
                  orderby books.Category
                  select new { books.Reviews }).Single();
    Repeater2.DataSource = review;
    Repeater2.DataBind();
}
```

but it's not working. The problem is that I cannot access the Id of the Reviews table. That `books.Id == 13` belongs to Books table.

What do I need to change on the code behind and repeater?

Thanks.

Comment: You are mistaking single with first.

Comment: Why you can't access the Id of the reviews table? I can't get it.

Comment: I mean I don't know how to access it. If I try: `from books in entities.Reviews.Include("Book")` then I can access it, but the `orderby books.Category` becomes inaccessible.

Comment: Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: An invalid data source is being used for Repeater2.

Comment: Do Reviews belong to the entities? If they belong, what's the declaration of a review? Which are it's properties (I mean Id, etc) and which is the association with the book?

Comment: **Book:** _Properties:_ Id, Category. _Navigation Properties:_  Reviews. **Review:** _Properties:_ Id, Title, Content, Publisher, Author, Pages, BookId, CreateDateTime, UpdateDateTime. _Navigation Properties:_ Book

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
using (ELibraryEntities entities = new ELibraryEntities())
{
    var review = (from review in entities.Reviews
                  where review.BookId == BookId
                  select review).FirstOrDefault();
    Repeater2.DataSource = review;
    Repeater2.DataBind();
}
```

Using the above snippet, you get the first review from the reviews, which has been written for the book with Id equal to the given one, `BookId`.

**Note**: You get the first review, if there exist at least one review for this book. Otherwise the result of the query would be null.

For more clarification on how FirstOrDefault method works, please look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).